# VueJS & Laravel 5.4 on Tizen doesn't work

Tags: javascript, laravel, browser, vue.js, tizen

Hi I made application in laravel 5.4 and VueJS it works fine on every browser but on Tizen I'm getting only things from blade template, and no VueJS componnents.

I'm using bootstrap nav bars with drop down menu and its not working as well.

I tried Vue offical site with examples and they are working correctly on TV screen. What should I do now? Is there any option I can handle it?

Some compiling into the raw old JavaScrpt or smth? I think thats the problem in here.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you find any declaration of vue js support in tizen platform? I would like to suggest you to try the Hello World example from vue js by following this link ( https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ ) and make sure whether it works on tizen browser or not by yourself.

Comment: I installed tizen studio and tried site on emulator (with browser ver 2.0)and it works, but on the browser ver 1.1 which is on TV it doesnt.

I figured out that the problem is with laravel-mix, when im getting public/app.js file. Its not working on TV there.


After i made just vue from site and initialized new instance 
const vue=new Vue ({}); it works normaly so problem is with the file compiled by laravel-mix i guess... But i dont know if i should write new code or there is other solution.

Comment: I guess it's a version problem, as your code is working with ver 2.0 then may be ver 1.0 doesn't support it. It should be OK once the browser on TV will be updated to newer version. Moreover, you may ask here into this link ( http://developer.samsung.com/forum/en ) to know whether you need to adapt a different way for older version or not.

Comment: I handled it with https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim, the problem was with versions of ES6. And i downgraded sockets to 1.5 and its now working correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I handled it with github.com/es-shims/es5-shim, the problem was with versions of ES6. And i downgraded sockets to 1.5 and its now working correctly!